# Peer-to-Peer object synchronization protocol/framework

Tags: synchronization, delta

I'm investigating how to implement a protocol for remote synchronization of several peers. But can't even find theoretical articles on the topic, not speaking of complete libraries.
Here's what I would like to have as features:

- Suppose I have a list of objects:

```
class User { string Id; string Name; string Email; //etc}
List<User> myList;
```

- I want to able to synchronize that list and all properties of each object via network with another process
- Sync should be in master-master fashion, both parties should be able to make changes
- I want to transmit only changed properties
- Have optimistic concurrency, e.g. if process1 changes Name and process2 changes Email, this is not a conflict, and is merged both ways without manual resolution
- Have per property custom rules to resolve conflicts. E.g. if both parties have changed LastLogonTime - choose bigger value. If both parties changed Email, add this case to queue for manual resolution

My question: are there existing implementations of similar protocol or at least articles with theory, so I don't have to invent it from scratch?